# MSBuild copying all library files over

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

One of our .net project refers to a library that do not exist in the given path, and therefore the project fails to compile on our dev machine (irrespective if we build using Visual Studio or MSBuild)

However on our Continuous Integration server the project builds just fine (we use jenkins which uses msbuild).

The reason it succeeds is because the very first .csproj in the .sln has a copy local to true on an assembly, lets call it X. Apparently the same folder where this X reside, also contains the very missing library.

I see from the logs that when the "_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal" part runs, it copies over the missing assembly to the destination folder along with X.

Later when the subsequent project compiles under "corecompile", it magically refers to this missing assembly and succeeds.

I'd like my CI to fail when we cannot build in our environment. How can I make msbuild to not copy over all the files but only the one which is marked for copying?

Comment: Does X depend on the missing lib?  Why is that missing lib in the folder on the build machine and not locally on dev machines?  I'd suggest you make your dev machines and build machine uniform before going any further.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear but x is present local to the solution both on the server and machine. X and missing library are part of the same project.

Comment: what I was trying to get at was, why is the missing lib on the build machine in the same folder as X but not on a dev machine?

Comment: The missing library is there in the same folder as X on the dev machine as well. The msbuild/VS on dev machine do not move the missing library from folder X and fails to compile the project, however msbuild on the CI server copies the missing assembly from folder X and magically refers to it and succeeds. So there is some discrepancy.

Comment: I see - reference evaluation in MSBuild uses standard .NET probing paths and all of the locations evaluated for libs can be seen in the MSBuild logging if you have it set to a verbose level.  Have you taken a peek at that?